# What is the best way to implement double validation in Quasar?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I want to allow either the checkbox to be checked, the text field to be filled in, or both in Quasar.
In the validation of this form, the error does not disappear even if the check box is checked after the validation error occurs.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/NewGorilla/pen/YzpOGZW)

index.html

```
<div id="q-app">
  <q-card class="my-card q-py-md">
    <q-card-section>
      <h3 class="text-h5 q-my-none">Fruits<span class="text-red">*</span></h3>
      <p>Which fruit did you eat?</p>
    </q-card-section>
  <q-card-section>
    <q-field
      hide-bottom-space
      borderless
      item-aligned
      class="row q-pa-none"
      :rules="[fruitsRule]">
        <q-option-group
          :options="fruits"
          label="Notifications"
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="fruits_select"></q-option-group>
      </q-field>
      <q-input
        class="q-mt-md"
        v-model="fruits_other"
        label="Other"
        :rules="[fruitsRule]"></q-input>
    </q-card-section>
  </q-card>
</div>
```

main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#q-app',
  data () {
    return {
      fruits_select: [],
      fruits: [
        { label: 'Apple', value: 1},
        { label: 'Banana', value: 2},
        { label: 'Orange', value: 3}
      ],
      fruits_other: ""
    }
  },

  methods: {
    fruitsRule () {
      if (!this.fruits_select.length && this.fruits_other === ""){
        return 'Select one or more checkboxes or fill in the others.'
      }
    }
  }
})
```

My question is

1. How Can I fix the checkbox error?
2. Is this double validation the best way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few problems with your code and Quasar validation in general

1. Your checkboxes are not triggering validation at all. The reason is you are missing `v-model` on `q-field`. Without it, the rules are not executed for checkboxes

```html
<q-field hide-bottom-space borderless item-aligned class="row q-pa-none" v-model="fruits_select" :rules="[fruitsRule]">
  <q-option-group :options="fruits" label="Notifications" type="checkbox" v-model="fruits_select" />
</q-field>
```

2. Your custom rule also seems wrong. According to the docs:

> Your custom validator will be a function which returns `true` if validator succeeds or `String` with error message if it doesn’t succeed

But your `fruitsRule` **never** retuns `true`. Fix:

```js
fruitsRule () {
  return this.fruits_select.length > 0 || this.fruits_other !== "" || 'Select one or more checkboxes or fill in the others.'
}
```

3. Quasar always check the rules only for the component which model has changed. So when you change the value in textbox, rules for checkboxes are not re-evaluated

Easiest thing to fix this is to use `<QForm>`, which has a method `validate()` that triggers the validation of every field in the form and execute it whenever one of the models changes:

```html
<q-form ref="form">
  <q-field hide-bottom-space borderless item-aligned class="row q-pa-none" v-model="fruits_select" :rules="[fruitsRule]">
    <q-option-group :options="fruits" label="Notifications" type="checkbox" v-model="fruits_select" />
  </q-field>
  <q-input class="q-mt-md" v-model="fruits_other" label="Other" :rules="[fruitsRule]" />
</q-form>
```

```js
watch: {
    fruits_select() {
      this.$refs.form.validate()
    },
    fruits_other() {
      this.$refs.form.validate()
    }
  },
```

Using `QForm` makes sense when you have more controls. You have only two so of course, you can leave out the `QForm`, place `refs` directly on both controls and use watchers to trigger the validation of the other control.

It is not very good solution but unfortunately the Quasar's internal validation is pretty limited. If you forms gets little bit more complicated I would recommend using external validation library - for examle Vuelidate

[Demo](https://codepen.io/liwoj/pen/mdOGREY?editors=1011)

UPDATE: Updated my demo so all models are grouped together to one object. This allows only use single `deep` watcher to trigger all validations...

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer.
As you say, this is part of the form and the original is more complicated.
Vuelidate looks very good so I'll try.
Thank you very much!